# Model validation failing for valid form submission

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table named EFT_BANK_INFO. Due to reasons I won't get into, I had to split up the form into 2 separate forms. This means that half the fields for this table are edited from one view, and half from another.

Everything was working great, until I added form validation to the tables model .cs file. While the codes syntax is correct, all submissions from both forms are labeled as being invalid, preventing me from updating, deleting, and adding rows to the table. It is marked as invalid due to the separation; i.e; I have Required fields in the model for the second portion of the fields, so when I submit data for one half of the fields, the other fields not part of the view/submission are marked as being invalid because no data was received for them.

A potential workaround would be to artificially satisfy the validation for the unwanted fields by inserting values for those fields in the C# controller during the create process. I could also do this for the edit process.

I was wondering if there's a better alternative, given I must have it structured this way. I'd like it to only validate the relevant fields in the model, and not validate all of them for the submission, which is causing the error. No code is really necessary since I have no bugs and know what is wrong, this is more of a theory/solution identification problem. Thanks.

Comment: use view models that have the split objects and their validations

Comment: You can just validate specific fields but if you are doing this then why not just split the models into two separate ones at this point as your models aren't really representative anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).

> A view model represents only the data that you want to display on your view/page, whether it be used for static text or for input values (like textboxes and dropdowns).

See the accepted answer on the question linked above.